# How to uninstall any program if Windows XP's Add and Remove unable to uninstall?

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall, sp3

How to uninstall any program if Windows XP's Add and Remove unable to install? because it's asking for source .msi file to uninstall and i doesn't have source file now. it's deleted long ago.

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/147260/windows-xp-remove-program-files

Answer (score 1):

[Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) should get rid of it.

Comment: no it's giving same error

Comment: Try Revo Uninstaller Pro. It's a free, fully functional trial which works for 30 days. It's forced uninstall option should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using [ccleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) - usually it cleans up missing links to programs or programs left in a weird state or uninstallable.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when the installed programs database gets messed up. In a nutshell the workaround is to remove the problem application from the installed-db and remove the program manually, or alternatively, remove from install-db, install the program again, and now finally uninstall properly using Add/Remove Programs.

If it is MS Office you're having trouble with, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301.

It is possible to use the now deprecated [Windows Installer Cleanup utility](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Secure-cleaning/Windows-Installer-CleanUp-Utility.shtml) utility for other programs but only with caution as it can easily create more problems than it solves. I would try ccleaner, as mentioned by *ccisystems,* first though.

Comment: why is  this answer downvoted? I'm not complaining. If there's a mistake I'd like to correct it. If it's plain old wrong, I'll remove it. Either way I'd like to know. Thanks.