# Windows XP remove program files

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall, reinstall

When I am trying to remove program from "Add or Remove Programs" I get an dialog with ability to chose instalation file. But I didn't have that file. So I can't remove program...

Is there any another way to remove it?

UPDATE: I need program that can remove application without application uninstaller. The program is Microsoft Silverlight.

P.S. I need to remove it for install new version of it.

Comment: Please tell us which software this is about. Might be easier to help if we know.

Comment: microsoft silverlight

Comment: If you have additions to your question, please edit your question. If you post it in the comments, people might overlook it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Windows install cleanup utility: [KB290301](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301).

Select Silverlight from the list and then download Silverlight again, and reinstall it.

Note this program does not remove the files or folder, it only removes the installer configuration - meaning Windows no longer thinks there is an existing installation - corrupt or otherwise. If you never wish to reinstall the program, you will need to manually delete the folders off your drive - and I would probably then recommend running a good Registry cleaner, such as the one found in *CCleaner*  - but as always, be sure to follow the prompts to backup the Registry before making any changes. If you are going to reinstall the latest version of Silverlight and will do so in the same location, you do not need to delete the folders manually.

Answer (score 1):

If the uninstaller does not work, your only option is to uninstall manually.

To do this, you will typically have to remove:

- files the software installed
- registry entries it installed
- possibly stop and remove services it installed (not all do this)

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to find out what you need to remove (that's why uninstallers exist). You can try searching for " uninstall manually" to see whether other people had the same problem, maybe you find instructions. Or contact the software's manufacturer (if you have support), failure to uninstall is a major defect in a software.

Otherwise, your only option is to go manually through all folders where the program might be installed, and delete its files. Of course, it goes without saying that you should *never* do this without a good, recent backup, as you might trash your Windows installation. The same goes for cleaning up the registry.

Ultimately,you may even have to reinstall Windows to get rid of the software if you can't find its files. Alternatively, if this is feasible, you could get/install a clean copy of Windows (possible in a virtual machine), make a list of all files on the HDD, install the SW, then make another list.Compare them to see where the software installed stuff; that's what you have to remove.

But again, there is no safe, foolproof way to deinstall a software that does not have a proper uninstaller, short of reinstalling Windows :-(.

Comment: I believe that there should be a program that can do it.

Comment: @Anton: What makes you believe that? Seriously, if a program installation just dumps stuff randomly all over your harddrive, how is a generic uninstaller supposed to find it?

Comment: It removes at least registry entries and allow to install newer vervion. See Mehper C. Palavuzlar answer.

Comment: @Anton: Well, it cannot uninstall the program in the sense of "removing it completely". It may uninstall enough to allow re-running an installer; if that is enough, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**CCleaner**](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) for removing that program. It is free and has many useful options besides uninstalling software.

Comment: This program does not help. I got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try Nirsoft's [MyUninstaller](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/myuninst.html). It's just 44 KB.

MyUninstaller is an alternative and *free* utility to the standard Add/Remove applet of Windows operating system. It works on any version of Windows - from Windows 98 to Windows 7.

[image]

Comment: This program does not help. I got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a site for this problem:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555175

The part about the Windows Installer CleanUp Utility looks like it might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the program, then uninstall. Or, just install the new version over it.

Comment: This is worth a try. I should work, but if parts of the application have been removed manually it might still fail. Why? Well the installer might look for an existing installation to offer the choice of "remove" or "repair".