# Uninstalling a program which uninstaller doesn't work

Tags: uninstall

I recently accidentally deleted my appdata folder, so 50% of the programs went mad, including Aptana Studio. When I looked for the uninstaller, I started it, and the "Uninstall from here:" field was empty. I clicked uninstall anyway, but it did nothing. So basically now I can't uninstall it and make a fresh install. I can't delete the files manually because the settings will stay, and the fresh install will be loading them and not working either.

Comment: Related situation: http://superuser.com/questions/147260/windows-xp-remove-program-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from Ofir's answer, about the only other option you have are commercial registry cleaner utilities which find "abandoned" registry settings.  These work with varying degrees of success and can potentially do as much harm as help, so make sure if you use one you take precautions such as manually backing up your registry first.  Some of the more popular ones include:  [PC Tools Registry Mechanic](http://www.pctools.com/) and [CCCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)

Comment: In many cases,software will check the uninstall registry location to determine if the software is already installed. ("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") In most cases, if you delete this entry, the program files folder, and any registry entries in the the "HKLM\SOFTWARE" key that relate to the vendor, the software should be considered removed. What I would do is then reinstall the software to get the uninstaller back and then uninstall it to remove everything. Does this software not have a "repair installation" option?

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is a better answer than mine, but using regedit - you can probably find the relevant entries and delete them.